# findViewById() returns null for an inflated layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an `Activity` and its layout. Now I need to add a `LinearLayout` from another layout, `menu_layout.xml`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
```

After this, `findViewById()` returns null. Is there is any solution for that?

Note: I can't put both XML in one place, and using `<include>` also is not working.

Comment: Use **LayoutInflater**

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater;
  inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);              

  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout ,
                  null);

Comment: I got this much. But how can I use findviewbyid after this

Comment: It should be **layout.findViewById();**

Comment: Thanks man That worked :)

Comment: I using this as a Click event in LinearLayout that is still not working :(

Comment: Make **android:clickable="true"**  for _LinearLayout_

Comment: Thats done. Any way thanks a lot for your help . Rest Let me try. Ones again thanks Piyush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

When you *inflate* a layout, the layout is not in the UI yet, meaning the user will not be able to see it until it's been added. To do this, you must get a hold of a `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`,etc) and add the inflated `View` to it. Once they're added, you can work on them as you would with any other views including the `findViewById` method, adding listeners, changing properties, etc

### Code

```
//Inside onCreate for example
setContentView(R.layout.main); //Sets the content of your activity
View otherLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.other,null);

//You can access them here, before adding `otherLayout` to your activity
TextView example = (TextView) otherLayout.findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);

//This container needs to be inside main.xml
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

//Add the inflated view to the container    
container.addView(otherLayout);

//Or access them once they're added
TextView example2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);

//For example, adding a listener to the new layout
otherLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Your thing
    }
});
```

### Assuming

- main.xml contains a `LinearLayout` with the id `container`
- other.xml is a layout file in your project
- other.xml contains a `TextView` with the id `exampleTextView`

Comment: How can I writte a click event for that found linerlayout ? .

Comment: Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 layoutObject.findViewById();
```

Comment: I done with LayoutInflater. Its worked with out error. But I am using this one for a click event in there. Its still not working :(